# script to loop through multiple shell scripts concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I'm extremely new to Linux and python and programming in general.. and would so very much appreciate some assistance/guidance..

I've got multiple shell scripts that i need to run simultaneously, these are basically just messages that need to be sent out very frequently to test our server capacity/how it handles stress. they're kinda like sending emails from the command line.

I can loop through one script like this

```
While True:
text = "my shell script"
os.system(text)
```

(I'm sure I'm using the wrong terminology here, hope you guys can still understand though..)

what I would like to do is have one script that i can run, that loops through soo many of those scripts concurrently.

can anyone help me/guide me on how to do that? 
what i have so far is i've declared 10 string variables, each containing the shell script like this

```
var1 = "my shell script1"
var2 = "my shell script2"
```

but I don't know how to put all these things together, don't know where to start, tried going through other similar questions but I didn't understand what they really meant.. so Any help would be appreicated

Comment: You can use a `list` and the iterate over the list to execute the scripts

Comment: I recommend that you use supervisor. It is a linux script that runs your python scripts. If they fall it will wake them up again. Supervisor documentation: http://supervisord.org/

Comment: Do all the scripts need to run at the same rate, or does one run once a second while another runs once every 10 seconds?

Comment: they all need to run at the same rate, though knowing how to manipulate that would be very helpful